# Create property table and save for each item in listbox vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net

I have a small project about datagridview and listbox in vb.net. But I don't know how can i create property table for each item which is inserted to list box.

I don't know how to describe but It's like that

I have a datagridview as property table to display and modified data, a text box and button to insert data to listbox.

[image]

When I add item "Shape1" it will create property table for"Shape1"

[image]

I fill data to property table for item "Shape1". Then save it as database.

[image]

Everytime when I click to item "shape1". It will show property table of shape1 again and I can modified and save it again.

Could you please tell me Is there any way or example to do like that.

Comment: A propertygrid would probably be a better choice than a DGV.  Edit the Props of a Shape class, then (I guess) add it to a collection bound to the listbox.

Comment: I checked property grid. You totally right. It's better than datagridview. But could you please tell me more detail. How can I create property table for each item when it's added and how can I save it when fill data to property done. I think i need to save it as datavase here for not lose data when I exit this application

Comment: Drop the idea of a "property table" - I dont even know what you mean by that.  From the pictures you need a class with those properties.  Edit them in the prop grid and use a List(of Shape) to store them.  Use the list as the Listbox data source

Comment: That sound like a doable idea. Let's me try with it. Thank you for your hint :)